# Automation Script to test Network Watcher Connectivity Check Feature

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

I am trying to build a automation powershell script on azurE whiCh can give me email alerts, by using network watchers new feature i.e connectivity check, the script can test out and send the alert whenever the vm is not reachable, can somebody explain mE how to do it or any article which I Can follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Azure network watcher connectivity check does **not** support send mail to users.

As a workaround, maybe we can set `Alert rules` to monitor Azure VM.

For example, we can set `Metric` to `Network In`, and the `Threshold` to 1, then enable Email owners, contributors and readers, and add the email address. In this way, when the VM receive network traffic less than 1 bytes over the last 5 minutes, we will get email. Settings like this screenshot:
[image]
[image]

More information about set metric alerts, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-alerts-portal).

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Does this helps in VPN Gateways?

Comment: @MarkHenry that just work for Azure VM, If you want to test VPN connectivity, we can use diagnostics logs for virtual network gateway, please refer to this link, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2014/12/18/diagnose-azure-virtual-network-vpn-connectivity-issues-with-powershell/

Comment: Ye I'll look into that.